# postgresql order by group

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I use below query get rows `1,3,4,5,6` in first table, I want to know how to order by `ParentTagId` then order by name    final get two arrays/rows `1,3,5` and `1,4,6`

```
var query = 'SELECT * FROM "ArticleTag" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "Tag" ON (
    "ArticleTag"."TagId" = "Tag"."TagId"
  ) WHERE "ArticleId" = $1 ORDER BY "ParentTagId" DESC';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Tag"(
"TagId" SERIAL NOT NULL,
"ParentTagId" integer,
"Name" varchar,
PRIMARY KEY ("TagId")
);

TagId | ParentTagId | Name |
1     |             | a   |
2     |             | b   |
3     | 1           | z   |
4     | 1           | f   |
5     | 3           | g   |
6     | 4           | z   |

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "ArticleTag"(
"ArticleTagId" SERIAL NOT NULL,
"ArticleId" integer NOT NULL,
"TagId" integer NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY ("ArticleId") REFERENCES "Article" ("ArticleId") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY ("TagId") REFERENCES "Tag0" ("TagId") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY ("ArticleTagId")
);

ArticleTagId | ArticleId | TagId |
0            | 0         | 1     |
1            | 0         | 3     |
2            | 0         | 4     |
3            | 0         | 5     |
4            | 0         | 6     |
```

**Update**
I wondering is it possible return multiple grouped rows.
I hope the result for above example
(number is TagId)
There are `[1,3,4,5,6]` in `ArticleTag` table , in `Tag` table `1>3>5` `1>4>6` is the parent child relation, there are two path, then return two array `[1,3,5] , [1,4,6]`

another example

if there are `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` in ArticleTag table, in Tag table `1>3>5` `1>4>6` `2` , are three path, then return three array `[1,3,5] , [1,4,6] , [2]`

Comment: can you show us what is your desire output?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Thanks for reply! I updated in question.

Comment: sorry I dont understand your notation. Not sure what is a row what is a field. I will have to pass

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about your question but this returns Tagid `1,4,3,5`

**[SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c5b5d/4)**

```
SELECT *
FROM "ArticleTag"
LEFT JOIN "Tag" ON ("ArticleTag"."TagId" = "Tag"."TagId")
ORDER BY "ParentTagId" NULLS FIRST, "Name"   ;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| ArticleTagId | ArticleId | TagId | TagId | ParentTagId | Name |
|--------------|-----------|-------|-------|-------------|------|
|            0 |         0 |     1 |     1 |      (null) |    a |
|            2 |         0 |     4 |     4 |           1 |    f |
|            1 |         0 |     3 |     3 |           1 |    z |
|            3 |         0 |     5 |     5 |           3 |    g |
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I updated in question, I hope can find a way  return two group arrays

Comment: Now Im confused. What you mean two group arrays?

Comment: if there are  `[1,3,4,5,6]` in `ArticleTag` table , and in `Tag` table `1>3>5` `1>4>6` is the parent child relation, there are two path,  then return two array `[1,3,5] , [1,4,6]`

Comment: if there are `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` in `ArticleTag` table, and in `Tag` table `1>3>5` `1>4>6` `2` , there are three path, then return three array `[1,3,5] , [1,4,6] , [2]`